How to run `cd folder_name` in container of docker-compose and run it continuously?
I have a Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11 as normal

WORKDIR /portal-podrjadchika

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
ADD src/ ./src

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc libc6-dev wget libpq-dev unzip && apt-get clean && pip install poetry==1.8.3

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install

EXPOSE 8000

and docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.11'

x-build: &build
  build:
    context: .
  volumes:
    - ./src:/portal-podrjadchika/src
    - ./pyproject.toml:/portal-podrjadchika/pyproject.toml
    - ./poetry.lock:/portal-podrjadchika/poetry.lock
  env_file:
    - docker.env

services:
  alembic:
    <<: *build
#    command: bash -c "cd src" stops the container
    tty: true

  celery:
    <<: *build
    command: bash -c "cd src && celery -A main.celery:celery_app worker"
    depends_on:
      - redis

  flower:
    build:
      context: .
    <<: *build
    command: bash -c "cd src && celery -A main.celery:celery_app flower"
    depends_on:
      - celery
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"

  db:
    image: postgres:14.7-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=portal_podrjadchika
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=portal_podrjadchika
      - POSTGRES_DB=portal-podrjadchika
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    image: redis:7.4.1-alpine3.20
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

volumes:
  postgres-data:

I need to make sure that in alembic container cd src happens and one still have the ability to run terminal for this container. With command: bash -c "cd src" it runs the command and then stops the container:

How to run cd src and to have the ability to open terminal for container alembic?
